# Prove that a radial force field is conservative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A radial or "central" force field $\mathbf{F}$ in the plane can be written in the form $\mathbf {F}(x,y)=f(r)\mathbf{r} $, where $\mathbf {r}=x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf {j}$ and $r=\Vert \mathbf {r}\Vert$. Show that such a force field is conservative.

This problem is an exercise of  Apostol Vol. II and came immediately after  the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Line Integrals (SFTCLI) (the first fundamental theorem is ennounced after the SFTCLI and also after this problem ).
It is said that a vector field $\mathbf {f}$ is conservative if it is a gradient of some scalar field $\varphi$, which is called the potential function of  $\mathbf {f}$. It is all I know to prove this, by now I don't know how to prove that $\mathbf {F}$ is a gradient. I verified that $\varphi_{xy}=\varphi_{yx}$ (where $\varphi$ is supposed to be the potential  function of $\mathbf{F}$) but I know that is not a sufficient argument to say that $\mathbf{F}$ is a gradient.
$$\mathbf {F}(x,y)= xf(r)\mathbf {i} +yf(r)\mathbf {j}=\nabla_{\varphi}$$
$$\varphi_{x}=xf(r), \varphi_{y}=yf(r) $$
$$\varphi_{xy}=xf'(r)\frac{\partial r}{\partial {y}}=\frac{xyf'(r)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
$$\varphi_{yx}=yf'(r)\frac{\partial r}{\partial {x}}=\frac{xyf'(r)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

What can I do?

Comment: Switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: Is $F$ required to be defined at the origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe an anti-derivative of $rf(r)$ is given by
\begin{align}
F(r) = \int^r_0 \tau f(\tau)\ d\tau.
\end{align}
In particular, if $r = \|\mathbf{r}\|$, then it follows from FTC and chain rule that
\begin{align}
\nabla F(r) = rf(r)\nabla\mathbf{r}.
\end{align}
Moreover, observe that
\begin{align}
\nabla \mathbf{r} = \frac{x}{r}\mathbf{i} +\frac{y}{r}\mathbf{j},
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\nabla F(r) = f(r)(x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf{j}).
\end{align}

Comment: Indeed, note that you only need $f$ to be continuous!!

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the remark. I definitely implicitly made the assumption that $f$ is continuous since it's a problem from physics.

Comment: Hi,here you use FTC for line integrals ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to verify this is to use the following theorem:

Let $\mathbf{F}(x,y)=P(x,y)\mathbf{i} + Q(x,y)\mathbf{j}$. If $P,Q$ are both continuously differentiable on a simply connected open region (the entire plane is such a region), then $\mathbf{F}(x,y)$ is a gradient if and only if

$$P_y = Q_x \quad \text{ for all }(x,y)$$

EDIT- As pointed out by Ted in the comments below this theorem will actually NOT work for this particular instance. I will keep the answer here because frequently this WILL be the theorem you use to show that a given vector field is a gradient.

Comment: But $\Bbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is *not* simply connected!

Comment: Are you sure it is  an "if and only if" statement?

Comment: @Sama I actually copied the theorem verbatim to make sure I wasn't shying on the assumptions :) The theorem isn't proven because its from a Cal III text, but the source is still reliable I think. This is actually the book I go to when I need reminders for "computational" calculus and not "theoretical" analysis. I am linking a picture:

Comment: @Sama  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpTte.jpg

"iff" = if and only if, I have double-checked to verify in the restricted assumptions proof he gives that he proves both directions

Comment: @Sama Actually ted here is correct. You can't use the theorem here, because the partials are undefined at the origin. Nonetheless its still useful to keep in mind in general. Please switch best answer back to the above because it is better suited for your particular question.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\nabla \times \bracks{\mrm{f}\pars{r}\vec{r}} & =
 \bracks{\nabla\mrm{f}\pars{r}}\times\vec{r}\ +\
\mrm{f}\pars{r}\nabla\times\vec{r}
=
\mrm{f}'\pars{r}\,\
\overbrace{{\vec{r} \over r} \times \vec{r}}^{\ds{\vec{0}}}\ +\
\mrm{f}\pars{r}\
\overbrace{\nabla\times\nabla\pars{{1 \over 2}\,r^{2}}}^{\ds{\vec{0}}}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\vec{0}}
\end{align}