# Prove that a radial force field is conservative on $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

> A radial or "central" force field $\mathbf{F}$ in the plane can be written in the form $\mathbf {F}(x,y)=f(r)\,\mathbf{r} $, where $\mathbf {r}=x\mathbf{i}+y\mathbf {j}$ and $r=\Vert \mathbf {r}\Vert$. Show that such a force field is conservative on $\Bbb R^2 - \{0\}$.

It is can be easily shown that it is a gradient on $\Bbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$ as shown by @JackyChong here ([Prove that a radial force field is conservative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609934/prove-that-a-radial-force-field-is-conservative)). I am guessing that $\mathbf{F}$ is also a gradient on $\Bbb R^2$ which is what I'm unable to prove.

The main issue as one can guess is with the point $(0,0)$ as $\nabla \mathbf{r}$ doesn't exist at $(0,0)$. My idea was to rewrite the line integral, $\int_{a}^{b} \textbf{F}(\alpha(t))\cdot  \boldsymbol{\alpha}(t)^{'} dt$  as

$$\int_{a}^{c-\epsilon }\textbf{F}(\alpha(t))\cdot  \boldsymbol{\alpha}(t)^{'} dt\ \ +\ \ \int_{c-\epsilon}^{ c+\epsilon} \textbf{F}(\alpha(t))\cdot  \boldsymbol{\alpha}(t)^{'} dt\ \ +\ \ \int_{c+\epsilon}^{ b} \textbf{F}(\alpha(t))\cdot  \boldsymbol{\alpha}(t)^{'}  dt$$

by lineaity of line integrals.

Now assuming that $r(\alpha(c))=0 \ ie \  \alpha(c)=0$ and $\forall x \in  [a,b]-c\ ,\  \alpha(x)\ne0$

Then we have $$\int_{a}^{b} \textbf{F}(\alpha(t))\cdot  \boldsymbol{\alpha}(t)^{'} dt = \phi(c-\epsilon)-\phi(a)+\int_{c-\epsilon}^{ c+\epsilon} \textbf{F}(\alpha(t))\cdot  \boldsymbol{\alpha}(t)^{'} dt-\phi(c-\epsilon)_+\phi(b)$$

where $\phi(r) = \int^r_0 \tau f(\tau)\ d\tau$.

Let $\varphi(\epsilon) = \int_{c-\epsilon}^{ c+\epsilon} \textbf{F}(\alpha(t))\cdot  \boldsymbol{\alpha}(t)^{'} dt$

Now using the fact that $\varphi(\epsilon)$ and $\phi(r)$ are left continuous at zero, hence

$$\int_{a}^{b} \textbf{F}(\alpha(t))\cdot  \boldsymbol{\alpha}(t)^{'} dt\ \ =-\phi(a)+\phi(b)$$

Now to truly show $\textbf{F}$ is a gradient we need this for all piece-wise smooth paths and these paths can pass  through $0$ arbitrary number of times which I'm unable to deal with using the simply minded idea above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working too hard. Referring to the answer in the linked post, you can see directly that if you set $\phi(x,y) = F(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$, then (using the actual definition of the partial derivatives at the origin)
$$\nabla\phi(0,0) = (0,0) = \mathbf F(0,0).$$
Thus, you have a potential function on all of $\Bbb R^2$, not just away from the origin.